# Saving Editable Tables in Shiny Dashboard at User discretion to allow updates to functions outside table

Tags: r, shiny

I am very experienced with R, but my Shiny experience is rather intermediate. I am a mathematician, not a UI expert. I have a predictive model that I am wanting to user Shiny to gather information for some of the data. So, I am wanting to create a dashboard that allows user inputs into several tables. The updates to the tables need to be able to be saved to run the predictive model, but I don't want the model to run every time someone updates the input. Here is the generic code that I have used as a jumping off point.

```
    ### Libraries
    library(shiny)
    library(dplyr)
    library(DT)

    ### Data
    input_data <- data.frame(Brand = c("Brand1", "Brand2","Brand3"),
                         ratio = c (.5, .5, .5),
                         cost = c(2000, 3000, 4000),
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% 
      mutate(updated_price = cost * ratio)




       ### Module
       modFunction <- function(input, output, session, data,reset) {
  
      v <- reactiveValues(data = data)
      
      proxy = dataTableProxy("mod_table")
  
      observeEvent(input$mod_table_cell_edit, {
        print(names(v$data))
        info = input$mod_table_cell_edit
    str(info)
    i = info$row
    j = info$col
    k = info$value
    str(info)
    
    isolate(
      if (j %in% match(c("ratio","cost","updated_price"), names(v$data))) {
        print(match(c("ratio","cost", "updated_price"), names(v$data)))
        v$data[i, j] <<- DT::coerceValue(k, v$data[i, j])
        print(v$data)
        
        if (j %in% match("cost", names(v$data))) {
          v$data$updated_price <<- v$data$cost * v$data$ratio
        }
        if (j %in% match("ratio", names(v$data))) {
          v$data$updated_price <<- v$data$cost * v$data$ratio
        }
          } else {
        stop("You are not supposed to change this column.") 
          }
        )
    # replaces data displayed by the updated table
        replaceData(proxy, v$data, resetPaging = FALSE)  

      })
      
      ### Reset Table
      observeEvent(reset(), {
        v$data <- data # your default data
      })
  
      print(isolate(colnames(v$data)))
         output$mod_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
        DT::datatable(v$data, editable = TRUE)
    
      })
    }

   modFunctionUI <- function(id) {
      ns <- NS(id)
      DT::dataTableOutput(ns("mod_table"))
      
    }
    ui <-  basicPage(
        mainPanel(
      
          actionButton("reset", "Reset"),
          tags$hr(),
           modFunctionUI("editable"), 
          modFunctionUI("editable1"), 
          modFunctionUI("editable2")
        )
      )
    ### Shiny App

  
  server <-  function(input, output) {
    demodata<-input_data
    callModule(modFunction,"editable", demodata,
               reset = reactive(input$reset))
    
    demodata1<-input_data
    callModule(modFunction,"editable1", demodata1,
               reset = reactive(input$reset))
    
    demodata2<-input_data
    callModule(modFunction,"editable2", demodata2,
               reset = reactive(input$reset))
      }
    shinyApp(ui = ui,  server = server)
```

I am wanting to figure out:

1. How do I reference these tables in functions outside of the table? The usual DT way was not working and I only want these to run after the user hits "save" (see below)
2. How can I add a "save" button, so when its calling my much more intensive function, it doesn't try to run it in between every input change, but only when the user is done making inputs?

I have tried naming the editable tables and calling them as such, but this reruns the functions every times a user updates any field.  In my actual dashboard, this is way too time consuming and will be confusing to the user. Also, when I try to call data$column, it says that the "object of type closure is not subsetable," so I cannot use the inputs outside of the table.

```
data <- allModule(modFunction,"editable", demodata,
               reset = reactive(input$reset))
```

Thank you!

Comment: As you have 2 separate questions, I would recommend breaking this into 2 separate posts, creating 2 different minimal reproducible examples. Your first question has to deal with returning values from a module. Your second question deals with delaying evaluation (which has nothing to do with modules).

Comment: From Mastering Shiny: [Module Input and Outputs](https://mastering-shiny.org/scaling-modules.html#inputs-and-outputs)

Comment: From Mastering Shiny: [Control Timing of Evaluation](https://mastering-shiny.org/basic-reactivity.html#on-click)